# Javascript, check if input is in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I am new to javascript and struggling with the use of arrays.

I am trying to check if user input value is in an array I declared called fruits. If it is I want to execute code. If it is not I want an alert displayed. I tried using the

> *instanceof*

method to check the value but the code doesn't execute any of the if else statement. Any ideas as to why?

```
$("#submit-btn").bind("click", function() {

           var comment = $("#comments");
            var commentValue = $.trim(comment.val());
            var index;
            var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
            for (index = 0; index < fruits.length; index++) {
                text += fruits[index];


            if (commentValue.length === 0) {
                alert('Comments are required to continue!');
            } 
            else if (commentValue instanceof fruits){
                execute code
                });
            }
            else {
                alert('not a valid fruit');
            }

            return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I suspect you're confusing [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) with [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: try `if(fruits.indexOf(commentValue) !== -1) {execute code }`

Answer (score 0):

Your first if should be outside the for loop.

Inside you simply change the else if to

```
if(commentValue === fruits[index])
```

And then you move the code inside the else out after the for loop.

A simpler way of doing it would be:

```
if (commentValue.length === 0) {
        alert('Comments are required to continue!');
       return false;
} 

if(fruits.indexOf(commentValue) > -1) {
    execute code
    return false;
}

alert('not a valid fruit');
return false;
```

Comment: Ptting the for loop in the middle of the if-statement would break it no? This method doesn't work when I try it

Answer (score 0):

Try indexOf(), if indexOf return anything bigger then -1, you have match

like this:

```
else if (commentValue.indexOf(fruits[index]) > -1){
```